# 'NSMutableDictionary' is not convertible to '[NSObject : AnyObject]' swift 2.0

Tags: swift2

After updating to swift 2.0
There occurs some error that used to be correct before, 
And Here is the code

```
let dict = NSMutableDictionary()   
dict[NSLocalizedDescriptionKey] = "Failed to initialize the application's saved data"
dict[NSLocalizedFailureReasonErrorKey] = failureReason   
dict[NSUnderlyingErrorKey] = error      
error = NSError(domain: "YOUR_ERROR_DOMAIN", code: 9999, userInfo: dict as [NSObject: AnyObject])
```

And the error messages is below:

```
'NSMutableDictionary' is not convertible to '[NSObject : AnyObject]'
```

Any idea of how to fix it?

Comment: do a clean build, your code is working fine for me.

Answer (score 2):

I cannot reproduce your problem, but a couple of suggestions that avoid `NSMutableDictionary` altogether (thus eliminating the cast):

1. You can use Swift `Dictionary` directly, eliminating the need for the cast:

   ```
   var dict = [NSObject: AnyObject]()
   dict[NSLocalizedDescriptionKey]        = "Failed to initialize the application's saved data"
   dict[NSLocalizedFailureReasonErrorKey] = failureReason
   dict[NSUnderlyingErrorKey]             = error
   ```
2. You can also declare the dictionary and the keys/values in single statement, too:

   ```
   let dict: [NSObject : AnyObject] = [
       NSLocalizedDescriptionKey        : "Failed to initialize the application's saved data",
       NSLocalizedFailureReasonErrorKey : failureReason,
       NSUnderlyingErrorKey             : error
   ]
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I have ran through your code and i modified as below. please have a look at below code:

```
var dict = NSMutableDictionary() as [NSObject : AnyObject]
let error :NSError = {    return NSError(domain: "YOUR_ERROR_DOMAIN", code: 9999, userInfo: dict as [NSObject: AnyObject]) }()

dict[NSLocalizedDescriptionKey] = "Failed to initialize the application's saved data"
dict[NSLocalizedFailureReasonErrorKey] = "hello"
dict[NSUnderlyingErrorKey] = error
```